# How to sync mongoose and remote elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am using mongoosastic plugin for elasticsearch... And when start server I get:

```
Server started
Mapping created
{ acknowledged: true }
Indexed 298 documents
```

Elasticsearch create index but not sync documets

Here is how I connect to remote host:

```
schema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts: [
        'MY IP:9200'
    ]
});
```

Anyone know what can couse problem? When I use it in local everything works fine...

Also I am using Elasticsearch v2.3

Comment: Why do you say that the document were not synched when the server outputs "Indexed 298 documents"?

Comment: Because I can't find that documents on elastic server. It create index but don't add documents... I found what is problem it looks like mongoosastic don't work with last version of  Elasticsearch server.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you should call synchronize()

```
var myDocument = mongoose.model('Document');

myDocument.synchronize();
```

You can find how to control the number of sync documents in the mongoosastic [documentation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#indexing-an-existing-collection)